# Why does my login fail when using InMemory db provider?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, .net-6.0, in-memory-database

I've got and `AuthUser` class, which works great when using ef core with SQL

However, when I try to use the `InMemory` database provider, 2 issues occur

1. My user cannot be found with `UserManager<AuthUser>.FindByNameAsync()` and instead I have to do something like `UserManager<AuthUser>.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == "")`
2. When I do find the user, and try to actually log in with `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()` , the login fails even though the password is correct

I noticed that whenever I retrieve my `AuthUser`, the `NormalizedUserName` and `NormalizedEmail` fields are not upper cased, as they normally are. Is that what causes the issues?

I tried overriding the properties like this, but it didn't seem to help

```
public override string NormalizedUserName { get => base.UserName.ToUpper(); set => base.NormalizedUserName = value; }
```

I also tried just setting the values explicitly on create, and also updating them, but the changes get reversed every time I retrieve the user from UserManager

AuthUser.cs

```
public class AuthUser : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser<string>
{
    public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
    public string? PasswordResetKey { get; set; }
}
```

configuration

```
builder
    .ToTable("AspNetUsers");
builder
    .HasKey((e) => e.Id);
builder
    .Property((e) => e.Id)
    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: Just a though: isn't creating new EF context create new instance of the inmemory database?

Comment: @Selvin The user was created using the same InMemory db as the one used when trying to log in, if that's what you mean. In fact I can see the user inside `UserManager.Users`, when I attempt the login so I'm sure its the same context

Comment: Maybe better to use [EF Core in Memory using SQLite](https://www.meziantou.net/testing-ef-core-in-memory-using-sqlite.htm) ?